# Laravel подмена model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php8

Проблема.
Controller Crud принимает два параметра, `int,request`.

По сути `id/nameTable`.

В контроллере приходится дублировать проверку, к какой модели относится id.

Есть такая шутка как приявязка к модели.

МОгу я реализовать проверку зарание в boot и передать нужную мне мадель для дальнейшей работы ,а не дублировать проверку во все круде?

Краткое описание можели работы.

```
 public function index(DetailContactsRequest $request): mixed
{
if($request->tab === 'users'){
    User::update($request->all());
}elseif($request->tab === 'authors'){

   Authors::update($request->all());

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware для этой задачи подойдет идеально:

1.Создаете middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{   
    if ($request->tab === 'users') {
        $model = User::find(...);
    } elseif ($request->tab === ...) {
        // ...
    }

    $request->merge(["model" => $model]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

2.Используете модель из запроса в контроллере:

```
$request->model->update($request->all());
```

Comment: Это работает,спасибо.